# Sql Server : Bind Xml schema to a column of a Table

Tags: sql-server, xml

First of all, I am completely new to these things, so please don't be tough.
I am creating an XML Schema as :

```
USE SampleDatabase;
GO
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION ManuInstructionsSchemaCollection AS
'<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/adventure-works/products" 
xmlns:prod="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/adventure-works/products"> 
<xs:element name="Product"> 
<xs:complexType> 
<xs:sequence> 
<xs:element ref="prod:ProductID" /> 
</xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType> 
</xs:element> 
<xs:element name="ProductID" type="xs:integer" /> 
</xs:schema> 
';
GO
```

Binding the xml schema to the table as :

```
CREATE TABLE ProductDocs
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductDoc XML(ManuInstructionsSchemaCollection)
);
```

Inserting Xml data into the table as:

```
INSERT INTO ProductDocs
    VALUES(
        N'<Product> 
        <ProductID>1</ProductID> 
    </Product>');
```

But, then it gives the error:

```
XML Validation: Declaration not found for element 'Product'. Location: /*:Product[1]
```

Am I binding the schema correctly? I have searched a lot but I was not able to figure out the things. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining your schema like this.

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION ManuInstructionsSchemaCollection AS
'<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" > 
<xs:element name="Product"> 
<xs:complexType> 
<xs:sequence> 
<xs:element ref="ProductID" /> 
</xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType> 
</xs:element> 
<xs:element name="ProductID" type="xs:integer" /> 
</xs:schema>
';
```